# How to replace a PostgreSQL pivot table field (foo_id) in the SELECT of a request by its value taken from the foo table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Below is my current request made in the `foo_bar` pivot table:

```
SELECT
    foo_id AS foo,
    COUNT(foo_id) AS total
FROM foo_bar
GROUP BY foo_id
```

How to replace the value of `foo_id` in the `SELECT` by `foo.name` taken from `foo` table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the table `foo`, assuming both have a `foo_id` to join the tables:

```sql
SELECT
    f.name,
    COUNT(fb.foo_id) AS total
FROM foo_bar fb
JOIN foo f
   ON f.foo_id = fb.foo_id
GROUP BY f.name
```

Comment: `foo_id` is ambiguous in `COUNT()`, it would need to be qualified with a table alias. Better yet, use `COUNT(*)`.